# Jumping to another section in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I want to jump from one section in the script to another section in the same PowerShell script. My script is only going from top to bottom right now, but I have several tasks. e.g. I want to be able to choose from a task list in the beginning of the script and go to task number 2 skip task 1.

I hope this makes any sense for you. Take a look at my script:

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "welcome to my powershell script..."
""
""
""
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Choose a task:"
""
""

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "1. Clean up"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "2. Uninstall Pre-Installed Apps" 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "3. Something should be written here"
""
""
""

While ($Valg -ne "1" -or $Valg -ne "2" -or $Valg -ne "3") {

    $Valg = Read-Host "Choose a number from the task list"

    If ($Valg –eq "1") { Break }
    If ($Valg –eq "2") { Break }
    If ($Valg –eq "3") { Break }

    if ($Valg -ne "1" -or $Valg -ne "2" -or $Valg -ne "3") {
        ""
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Ups. Try again..."
    }
}

#### 1. First task should come here (clean up)
#some code here for the "cleaning up" task 

#### 2. Second task here
#some code here for the "Uninstall Pre-Installed Apps" task

#### 3. Third task there
#Some code for the third task here

#### And so on...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating answer to complete script based on inputs by "bluuf" and "majkinator".
Use the Switch-Case construct along with Functions like below. **This is complete working solution.**

```
#region Function Definitions. These come first before calling them
        function FirstTask
        (
            [string] $inputVariable
        )
        {
            "write any scipt for First task here without quotes. Input is: " + $inputVariable
        }

        function SecondTask
        {    
            "write any scipt for Second task here without quotes"
        }
        function ThirdTask
        {    
            "write any scipt for Third task here without quotes"
        }    

#endregion

#region Showing Options
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "welcome to my powershell script..."
""
""
""
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Choose a task:"
""
""

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "1. Clean up"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "2. Uninstall Pre-Installed Apps" 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "3. Something should be written here"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "0. Exit"
""
""
""
#endregion

#region Getting input
While ($true) {

    $Valg = Read-Host "Choose a number from the task list"

    If ($Valg –eq "0") 
        { 
            "Thanks for using my utility"; 
            Break; 
        }

    If (($Valg -ne "1") -and ($Valg -ne "2") -and ($Valg -ne "3") -and ($Valg -ne "0")) {
        ""
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Ups. Try again..."
    }

    #region Main Code

    switch ($Valg) 
        { 
            1{
                FirstTask("sending input");
            } 
            2 {
                SecondTask;
            } 
            3 {
                ThirdTask;
            } 
            default { "Please select a correct option."}
        }
    #endregion
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Hello @Amen and thank you very much for reply.

Like this you mean?


`
$Valg = read-host "Choose a number from the task list"
If ($Valg –eq ”1”) {Break;}
If ($Valg –eq ”2”) {Break;}
If ($Valg –eq ”3”) {Break;}

$Valg = 2

switch ($Valg) 
    { 
        1{
            Get-date;
            break;
        } 
        2 {
            Get-Service
            break;
        } 
        3 {
            Get-ChildItem
            break;
        } 
        default {Get-NetAdapter}
    }
`

Comment: Yes @PhillipLuiSkouGreen, that should work. Although you can simplify it further as below. Unless you need the code I deleted from this: ***$Valg = read-host "Choose a number from the task list" switch ($Valg) { 1{ Get-date; break; } 2 { Get-Service break; } 3 { Get-ChildItem break; } default {Get-NetAdapter} }***

Comment: I would use functions and depending on the type of script decide to use a switch statement or not (and in the switch i would of course call the functions)

Comment: @bluuf You are talking about enhancing the code using functions. But that is not the question. The question is only how to jump to various sections based on the value of a variable, which you can do using **Switch** statement.

Comment: @PhillipLuiSkouGreen Please let us know if this resolves your problem or you need further help. If this helps you then please do mark this as answer by click on the tick mark under the arrows beside my response. You can optionally also up vote by clicking on the up arrow.

Comment: @Aman Sharma that's why I put it in the comments as a response on your solution, was not meant to critizize you or something, i only wanted to be helpfull.

Comment: @AmanSharma, 'jumping' is what functions do also. Son bluuf is correct and that is way better solution then swtich and can be even one lined.

Comment: @bluuf Yes, I added an answer using functions which doesn't even need a switch statement

Comment: Thanks for your comments @bluuf and majkinetor, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Well, you should still try to get rid of the switch as @majkinetor mentioned. See my answer.

Comment: @AmanSharma I'll go for your answer. Thank you :) that was very helpful for me. I have one last question before I close this one. How can I start the script from the start after I finish a task. e.g. after task two is done, I wan't the script to get back to the region with "showing options".. ?

Comment: @PhillipLuiSkouGreen I have updated the script as per your requirement. Please try and let us know if this is what you expect or you need any modifications in this.

Comment: @AmanSharma not exactly. e.g. when a user has pressed a number for a specific task and the task is done, the script is just ending as it is right now. Is it possible to get the script starting over, so that it will ask for a new task again? So I dosn't have to restart the script every time a task is done? 

And again. Thank you so much for the time you are using to help me out

Comment: Sure @PhillipLuiSkouGreen. Happy to help. I have updated the script in the answer. It will now perform the task and then after the task is done it will again ask for the options. I have kept number 0 as the option for exit. If the end user selects 0 then the script will exit. Please try the script from my answer again and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a *generic* solution which uses an `array` of `PSCustomObject` that represents the task (*message* and the *function to invoke*). It doesn't need a switch, you can simply add new Tasks to the array (and implement the desired function) without modifying the remaining script:

```
# define a task list with the messages to display and the functions to invoke:
$taskList = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Message = 'Clean up'; Task = { Cleanup }}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Message = 'Uninstall Pre-Installed Apps'; Task = { Uninstall }}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Message = 'Something should be written here'; Task = { Print }}   
)

# define the functions:
function Cleanup()
{
    Write-Host "Cleanup"
}

function Uninstall()
{
    Write-Host "Uninstall"
}

function Print()
{
    Write-Host "Print"
}


# let the user pick a task:
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Choose a task:"

$taskList | foreach -Begin { $i = 1;} -Process { 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ('{0}. {1}' -f ($i++), $_.Message) 
}

do 
{
    $value = Read-Host 'Choose a number from the task list'

}
while($value -match '\D+' -or $value -le 0 -or $value -gt $taskList.Count)

# invoke the task:
& $taskList[$value-1].Task
```

Comment: That is exactly what I thought in comments.

Comment: Hello @jissak. Thank you very much for your time to making a generic solution. Unfortunately it's to much for my basic understanding with powershell right now, so I'll go for the more simple solution. I will definitely save this one. Perhaps I can use your example another time :) Thank you